# How to set a my own form representation for my own type

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have created my own form type in my Symfony 2 project whose a child of the date type. I call it in the controller :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($customer)
 ->add('my_own_field_name', 'my_own_date_type', array())
 ->getForm();
```

In the twig template :

```
{{form_row(form.my_own-field_name)}}
```

Is it possible to say to Symfony2 to call my own twig for a representation of this field through the 'form_row' function instead of having the date type representation

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider having a look at [this part of the official SF2 documentation.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field)

As told in the doc, the getName method of your custom type helps SF2 find a custom form renderer. As your type name is `my_date_type`, SF2 will try to look for a `my_date_type_widget` block in a configured form templates list (as shown at the end of this post and in the official doc).

You just have to create a template `fields.html.twig` in your bundle `resources/views/Form/` folder that specifies this block as shown in the doc and add your own logic in it.

Don't forget to add the config lines

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'YourOwnBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

to tell symfony to always use this to render this form type.